# SQL syntax to excel formula

Tags: sql, excel

```
CASE WHEN var_1 IS NULL THEN 1 
     WHEN var_1 <2 THEN -3 
     WHEN var_1 <4 AND var_1>=2 THEN -1 
     WHEN (var_1 <8 AND var_1>=4) OR (pixel_1<2.5 AND var_1>=4) THEN 1 
     WHEN var_1 >=8 AND pixel_1>=2.5 THEN 2
     ELSE 0 END
```

I have this sql query above, and I'am trying to convert it into excel formula. So far I have tried this, and it does not seems to be right.

```
=IF(FA2="";1;IF(FA2<2;-3;IF(AND(FA2<4;FA2>=2);-1;IF(OR(AND(FA2<8;FA2>=4);AND(CU2<2,5;FA2>=4));IF(AND(FA2>=8;CU2=2,5);2;0)))))
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You need `XLOOKUP()`. Post few sample data then show desired output.

Comment: @Harun24hr honestly, I'am not sure how would it help you if I would create two columns with random numbers and create third column with 'desired' output.
1 1 3, it would look like this.
I think the question is clear, if someone is good with sql and excel, he would spot a mistake in my excel formula

Comment: There may multiple way to achieve expected result. IF, IFS, XLOOKUP and more few function can work. Without seeing data how we can suggest you best one. You wrote `IF()....` formula. How we will know either it work or not? How we can correct your formula if can see output?

Comment: So create a table of data and use your expression to check all the different conditions. Also, separate out the parts of the formulae and check each works.

Comment: @SolarMike I dont really know how to combine OR and AND statement in some cases as in this sql query above. It gets a little too complicated for me. I've done as much as I could with my current knowledge. That is why I'am asking for help here

Comment: So, start by each test individually before you combine them together. as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So, as an example of testing each expression I did this:

[image]

You can now repeat that for each expression so each works correctly then you can combine them. Just a case of testing the logic.

Note OR() will return True when any of its arguments is True. Make sure you check for , and ; as this is based on system settings.

Comment: still not getting the right answer, guess it is harder for me than you think:))

Comment: @Krish So without separating the bits out I think it will stay hard.

Comment: may be you could've pointed out where is mistake in my formula, so I would save a little bit of time?:)

Comment: I have shown you a tooll to be able to evaluate this and other logic situations - between doing your work for you and helping you LEARN, I will take the second option.

Comment: there are situations where one can learn more from an answer. And this is not a work, I'am just trying to do some things by myself, as I'am a consultant at small firm and trying to learn sql,python and excel to get jon in IT.
Thank hyou anyways!

Comment: I still cant uderstand how to combine two if(and statement with OR

Answer (score 0):

To know if a cell is NULL you can use the ISBLANK() function.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(FA2);1;IF(FA2<2;2;IF(AND(FA2<4;FA2>=2);3;IF(OR(AND(FA2<8;FA2>=4);AND(CU2<2,5;FA2>=4));4;IF(AND(FA2>=8;CU2>=2,5);5;6)))))
```

Also you missed the >= statement for the second *pixel_1* comparation.